# output from GridSearchCV to log (with parallel joblib)

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn

I'm running some hyperparameter tuning on a cluster.
The cluster automatically kills my job after some time.
When this happens, I lose all my preliminary results.
It would be great to store the preliminary results from `GridSearchCV` (the output that is printed to the console) in some file.
My plan was to use the logging library for this task.

**What I want to do:**
I would like to be able to redirect the output from `GridSearchCV` to my logger.
I tried to simply redirect all output from `sys.stdout` to my logger based on some suggestions found on this site.
However, it is not working.

Based on the information I found, I think the problem I face is that each process `GridSearchCV` is kind of independent from my main stdout.
I'm also not sure if there is a smarter way to do it - I tried to solve it with callbacks but with no success.

This is a minimal example:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np
import logging
import sys

class StreamToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, level):
       self.logger = logger
       self.level = level
       self.linebuf = ''

    def write(self, buf):
       for line in buf.rstrip().splitlines():
          self.logger.log(self.level, line.rstrip())

    def flush(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger('sklearn.model_selection._search')

    sys.stdout = StreamToLogger(logger, logging.INFO)
    sys.stderr = StreamToLogger(logger, logging.ERROR)

    X = np.random.randn(100,2)
    y = np.random.randn(100)

    reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=10, n_estimators=100)
    param_grid = {"gamma": [0.1]}

    gs = GridSearchCV(reg, param_grid, cv=5, verbose=3, n_jobs=1)
    gs.fit(X,y)
```

with `n_jobs=1` I get the preliminary results redirected to my logger:

```
[2023-11-13 12:01:23,382] [INFO] Fitting 5 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 5 fits
[2023-11-13 12:01:23,434] [INFO] [CV 1/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.730 total time=   0.1s
[2023-11-13 12:01:23,451] [INFO] [CV 2/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-1.663 total time=   0.0s
[2023-11-13 12:01:23,467] [INFO] [CV 3/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.310 total time=   0.0s
[2023-11-13 12:01:23,483] [INFO] [CV 4/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-1.536 total time=   0.0s
[2023-11-13 12:01:23,507] [INFO] [CV 5/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.841 total time=   0.0s
```

When I change it to `n_jobs=2`, the output becomes

```
[2023-11-13 11:58:54,220] [INFO] Fitting 5 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 5 fits
[CV 2/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.793 total time=   0.0s
[CV 1/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.111 total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-1.091 total time=   0.0s
[CV 4/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.139 total time=   0.0s
[CV 5/5] END ........................gamma=0.1;, score=-0.621 total time=   0.0s
```

(note that the first line is still forwarded to my logger but all the [CV X/5] lines are no longer redirected to my logger - thus, they would not be included in a .log file if I add a file handler).

An alternative approach via calling my script using `$ python file.py > "file.log" 2>&1` seems to not flush the buffer when the process is killed... Thus, I would prefer to use the logging approach.